# Changes made externally to database is not reflected back

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, mdf

I am trying to build a website in Visual Studio 12 using a local db(*.mdf file)
but once i run the site to test it.. and insert data through the website into my db, after a few runs, the changes are not reflected in the db. how can i fix this?

Comment: how do you know if even one `WRITE` successful?

Comment: Coz previous writes can be seen in the corresponding data tables

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem too but found the correct answer, in my case the problem was in the properties of the .mdf file.

As Luis.fr points in MSDN:

> Yes. It is copied to the bin\Debug folder when you compile. Depending on your settings, either each time you compile (and then each test starts with a clean database) or only when you update the database (the one you selected initially) yourself. Click on the database in the Solution explorer and look at its properties. The property "Copy to output directory" should be set to "copy if newer".
>
> It's done on purpose. That way, you can do all the tests you want without damaging your initial database. If you want to examine the results of the tests, you can use the Servers explorer or whatever tool you want to examine the changed database in the Debug folder.

So try to check that property, change its value and try again.
Regards